# Which crucible mode allows vehicles?

Tags: destiny

In crucible which gamemode lets you use vehicles? I've heard about vehicles on the beta and wondering if there still in the game.Or are the vehicles only allowed in certain maps?

Comment: I don't believe the *mode* is the defining factor of when you can or can't use vehicles. The map defines this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combined Arms is the Crucible type which is control *only* on maps with vehicles.

This is not always available, and will show up in the fifth slot (in the middle beneath the main 4) when open for the pre expansion maps, and above as one of the top two for post expansion maps.

Combined Arms is essentially Control but with a faster vehicle and heavy ammo respawn timer.

There are only 3 maps which can have vehicles, and @Adeese notes them in his answer (Moon - First Light, Mars - Bastion, and Earth - Skyshock).

Answer (score 3):

Vehicles are only allowed on certain maps. I was unable to find a list of all the PvP maps in the game, but I know there are at least 3 maps that allow vehicles: 1 on the Moon, 1 on Mars, and 1 of the new maps in the Dark Below expansion.